# fetch mysql data and encode to json with limited records per page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

i am working on moving map search with jquery birds-eye example. I converted mysql data to json with below php code

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include('dbhconfig.inc.php');

$response = array();

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM venddata");
$stmt->execute();
//$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as &$r) { // with reference
    // explode with comma, map with floatval
    $r['latlon'] = array_map('floatval', explode(',', $r['latlon']));
}
echo json_encode(array('results' => $rows)); // json encode
```

its showing all the records in json. but i want to show only 10 records per page and with total count and no.of pages in json. please see the below example.

http://sbadb.herokuapp.com/v1/bizs
its showing 10 records and at the bottom of the page i found below code

```
"meta": {
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 10,
    "count": 493,
    "total_pages": 50
  }
```

i want to show similar to above example. And the data which is fetch for mysql is

http://www.zesteve.com/jsondata.php

i dont have much knowledge in json. need some help

below code is using js file.

```
response_params_pagination: {
          page: function(data) {
            return data.meta.page;
          },
          per_page: function(data) {
            return data.meta.per_page;
          },
          total_pages: function(data) {
            return data.meta.total_pages;
          },
          count: function(data) {
            return data.meta.count;
          }
        },
```

conclusion is i want to paginate mysql data into json also it should include above meta content in the json.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with JSON is not the right approach. You should paginate the data with MySQL using `LIMIT` for example.

```
SELECT * FROM venddata LIMIT 10 OFFSET <yourpage*10>
```

(side-note: make sure you protect the query from sql-injection)

The query selects 10 rows starting with 11 (offset 10). Omit the offset for the first page. All you have to do now is pass the page number to your PHP script and use it to build your SQL query.

Use your already available meta settings array to make it more dynamic.

Comment: ok , but i need to use "meta" in my json data to make it work